# How to use kevlindev's intersectPolygonRectangle

Tags: javascript, svg, intersection

I have some trouble understanding which parameters to use with kevlindev's intersectPolygonRectangle function :
http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/index.htm#Anchor-intersectPolygonRectangl-23720

More precisely, what do r1 and r2 stand for, regarding to svg rect ?

```
Intersection.intersectPolygonRectangle = function(points, r1, r2) {
var min        = r1.min(r2);
var max        = r1.max(r2);
var topRight   = new Point2D( max.x, min.y );
var bottomLeft = new Point2D( min.x, max.y );

var inter1 = Intersection.intersectLinePolygon(min, topRight, points);
var inter2 = Intersection.intersectLinePolygon(topRight, max, points);
var inter3 = Intersection.intersectLinePolygon(max, bottomLeft, points);
var inter4 = Intersection.intersectLinePolygon(bottomLeft, min, points);

var result = new Intersection("No Intersection");

result.appendPoints(inter1.points);
result.appendPoints(inter2.points);
result.appendPoints(inter3.points);
result.appendPoints(inter4.points);

if ( result.points.length > 0 )
    result.status = "Intersection";

return result;
};
```

I understand that a rectangle is defined by 2 points (topleft and bottomright), so which values should I use for r1 and r2 ?

Although I managed to use other functions such as intersectCircleRectangle and intersectCirclePolygon, I can't find any working example for intersectPolygonRectangle on the web...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An SVG rectangle is described by `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height`.  Where `x` and `y` are the top left of the rectangle.

It looks like it doesn't matter which two points of the rectangle you provide, as long as they are diagonal.  The code sorts out what the top right and bottom left coordinates are.

So the following should work:

```
r1 = new Point2D(<rect X>, <rect Y>);
r2 = new Point2D(<rect X> + rect WIDTH>, <rect Y> + <rect HEIGHT>);
```